# How to Read JSON File

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I will be using the following code to get json from a request.

```
        Dim url As String = urlbuilder.ToString
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd)

        reader.Close()
        response.Close()
```

I've checked this out and the o (JObject) has the information.

I now need to play around with this data but in order not to incur costs while developing (the data is from a paid service) I have a sample of the output that I've save as a file. How do I amend the above code so that I temporarily read in the file instead of process a response. Ideally I would want it still as an JObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from a file on disk, replace your code with this:

```
Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\wherever\whatever.txt")
Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
```